# unexpected result when counting word length in c using for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

i am learning c language, and the program is about counting no of characters.

here is code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    double nc;
    for (nc=0;getchar() != EOF;nc++);
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

input

```
''
```

input in none.

the output which I am getting is 1.

online compiler [result](https://ideone.com/lnB5G1)

shouldn't be output equal to 0, not 1.unable to understand why is this coming.

thanks

Comment: OT: Seems strange to use a `double` for storing an integer count

Comment: Counting number of words or characters?

Comment: @4386427 OT2: By using `double`, certainly no counting trouble until about 18*10^15 iterations - at least a year of run time.

Comment: @interjay characters

Comment: @chux OT3: If `double` allows 1 year then `uint64_t` would allow like 10.000 years. Why limit your program to run just a single year. ;-)

Comment: @4386427 I cant even see to next year - I do not have 2020 vision ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you put a bit more effort in yor programming adding couple of lines of code everything would be clear:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int nc;
    int c;
    for (nc=0;(c = getchar()) != EOF;nc++)
    {
        printf("The char is '%c' code: 0x%02x\n", c >= 32 ? c : '.', c);
    }
    printf("%d\n", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/jfGK7h

And the mistery is solved. You have pressed the enter in the ideone input box and you have a new line there.

Comment: Using `isprint(c)` instead of `c >= 32` is  more idiomatic, yet either works well enough for learner code here. UV

Comment: @chux as it is not "real" program laziness won :)

Comment: @P__J__ thanks for the solution, it solved my query. didn't get that I had a new line in ideone input box. my fault

Comment: @P__J__  `c >= 32 ? c : '.'` this part to check the ascii coding character value right ?

Answer (score 1):

How did you input that **input**?

If you hit the `<enter>` key at the keyboard, then you got a single `\n` char, leading to that response.

Try this:

```
$ a.out
<Ctrl-D>
0
$ _
```

(`$` is the prompt, and `<Ctrl-D>` is the way to produce no input from a unix terminal)  Of course, `a.out` is the name of your program (you didn't show how it is called)

BTW, why do you end the output in a `\t` in `printf()` ??? `\t` is a tab character, not a new line.... `8-.`

Comment: i run this code in online compiler www.ideone.com, where i have put the enter key in input and after running it was showing empty input , and result as 1. now why add end character as `\t`, i am learning c language ( from c proramming language by kernigan and ritchie book) and want to test what a tab do in c that's all.

Comment: @prashantrana, and what about writing a `\n` ???  anyway, K&R is a very good book to learn C.  Clear, concise and very focused on the details.  All books from D. Ritchie hold perfectly to be used today without changing anything.

Comment: D. Ritche book is really good and holds concept and coding pratice today, i will update the  question to `\n` instead of `\t`

Comment: That's not necessary.  The `\t` confused me, because it allowed me to see the `D` part of the `^D` echoed character, and I was  wondering for a while, where did that `D` came.  The previous `^` was overwritten by the `1`, making it to appear as `1D` in the screen, which was nonsense. Not until I revised your code and saw the `\t` was I aware of the actual output.